# Recover Path in <_io.BufferedReader name='Path'> after browsing a file Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating an app with tkinter Python library, and have already this :

```
class Application(Tk) :

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.Launch = Button(self, text="Launch", command=self.launchCallBack)
        self.Browse = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.browseCallBack)
        self.pathlabel = Label(self)

        self.file = ''

        self.Launch.pack()
        self.Browse.pack()
        self.pathlabel.pack()

    def browseCallBack(self) :
        self.file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=self, mode='rb', title='Choose a file', initialdir = "D:\\Users\T0211254\MyApp\Bundle CUD-CAPELLA 431\melody\eclipse\workspace", filetypes=[("aird Files", "*.aird")])
        self.pathlabel.config(text=str(self.file))

    def launchCallBack(self):
        create_file(self.file)
```

The problem is that my `self.file` attribute returns me :

```
<_io.BufferedReader name='MyFilePath'>
```

And i just want to recover the `MyFilePath`.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is available on `BufferedReader`s in the `name` attribute, so `self.file.name` would get you what you want.

However, you probably want to use `filedialog.askopenfilename()` instead, to just get the name, not an open file object.